# Efficient element-wise vector times matrix ,multiplication in MKL

Tags: blas, intel-mkl

I have a vector

```
[2 3 4]
```

That I need to multiply with a matrix

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

to get

```
2 3 4
4 6 8
6 9 12
```

Now, I can make the vector into a matrix and do an element-wise multiplication, but is there also an efficient way to do this in MKL / CBLAS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a function in oneMKL called `cblas_?gemv` which computes the multiplication of matrix and vector.
You can refer to the below link for more details regarding the usage of the function.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-2-routines/cblas-gemv.html
If you have installed the oneMKL in your system, you can take a look at the examples which helps you to better understand the usage of the functions that are available in the library.